# FTP server PORT command parsing issue

Tags: c, string-parsing

I'll try to keep this simple.  Basically, whenever I call `ls` from the FTP command prompt, it always returns a 425, as seen in the relevant if statement in the code below:

It apparently is due to overflow in the line

```
sprintf(ip_decimal, "%d.%d.%d.%d", act_ip[0], act_ip[1], act_ip[2], act_ip[3]);
         local_data_addr_act.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_decimal);
```

Can anyone explain to me why this line is changing all my values for my IP address to 255?

Full code is below.

```
else if(!strcmp(command,"PORT"))
    {
     int act_port[2];
     int act_ip[4], port_dec;
     char ip_decimal[40];
     active=1;
     sscanf(command, "PORT %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&act_ip[0],&act_ip[1],&act_ip[2],&act_ip[3], &act_port[0], &act_port[1]);
     local_data_addr_act.sin_family=AF_INET;
     sprintf(ip_decimal, "%d.%d.%d.%d", act_ip[0], act_ip[1], act_ip[2], act_ip[3]);
     local_data_addr_act.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_decimal);
     port_dec=act_port[0];
     port_dec=port_dec<<8;
     port_dec=port_dec+act_port[1];
     local_data_addr_act.sin_port=htons(port_dec);
     if (connect(s_data_act,(struct sockaddr*)&local_data_addr_act, (int)sizeof(struct sockaddr))!=0){
       printf("%s%d\n",inet_ntoa(local_data_addr_act.sin_addr),ntohs(local_data_addr_act.sin_port)); 
       sprintf(buf, "425\r\n"); 
       send(sock2, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
       close(s_data_act);
      }
     else{
     sprintf(buf, "200\r\n");
     send(sock2, buf, strlen(buf), 0); 
      }
}
```

However, I have no idea why it is doing this.  What should I do to fix this problem?

The server returns:

```
PORT 127,0,0,1,217,89

PORT
255.255.255.25535028
```

sock1 and sock2 are my sockets.

If you need more info, or think the error is somewhere else, please ask, and I'll be all to happy to provide it.

Comment: Do I understand right that the `127,0,0,1,217,89` is parsed by your code to `255.255.255.2550`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It's actually just 4 255's.  I recently identified that as a problem that I have no idea how to fix.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl only the first four numbers though.

Comment: So please edit your question to reduce its scope to the string parsing. As this actually has nothing to do FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!strcmp(command,"PORT"))
{
     ...
     sscanf(command, "PORT %d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",&act_ip[0],&act_ip[1],&act_ip[2],&act_ip[3], &act_port[0], &act_port[1]);
```

To get to the `sscanf` call, the `command` must be equal to `"PORT"`. So obviously the `command` variable does not include the arguments. Hence the `sscanf` call fails. You'd know had you test the `sscanf` return value.

---

*You should learn using a debugger. Without that your chances on implementing an FTP server are low.*

*You should better pick an existing open-source implementation of FTP server, rather than implementing your own. That's an immense task, even an experienced developer would have troubles accomplishing.*